# AWS CodeBuild Download Source failed message authentication

Tags: aws-codebuild

Has anyone come across this failure message for AWS CodeBuild on the DOWNLOAD_SOURCE step that could provide some insight into how to resolve this error?

`Message authentication required for primary source and source version`

[image: AWS CodeBuild failed]

Answer (score 6):

This message will show when the GitHub personal token is invalid.